# Change part two class in div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want change part two of class name in each div into tag `<span>` from '.myclass_2' to 'yourclass', (in following html code). Here is my try with jQuery but they doesn't work true. How is fix it?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sTF3U/

```
<span>
    <div class="myclass_1 myclass_2">
        <a href="" class="click">Click Me_1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="myclass_1 myclass_2">
        <a href="" class="click">Click Me_2</a>
    </div>
</span>




var $this = $('.click'),
    $clone_1 = $('span').clone();
    alert($clone_1.html());

$('.click').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();   

    $clone_2 = $('span').clone();

    $clone_2.find('div').split(" ")[1].addClass('youClass');

    $clone.find('.auto_box2:last .mediumCell').each(function () {
        $(this).split(" ")[1].removeClass().addClass(unique());
    });

    var $result = $('span').clone();
    alert('ok');
})
```

Comment: Putting `<div>` elements inside `<span>` elements doesn't really make much sense.  A `<span>` is for inline content.

Comment: Also that code is clearly incorrect, but it's so incorrect that I can't tell even what it's intended to do. Can you describe what it is that the "click" events should do to the markup?

Comment: can you add how you expect the document to look after the edit has been applied? i can't make much from your question text but if i have a target...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("div.myclass_2").removeClass("myclass_2").addClass("yourclass");
```

BTW, a `<div>` inside a `<span>` is not valid HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Juse use `removeClass` passing the required class to remove and then use `addClass` passing the required class to add to any element. Try this

```
$(".myclass_2").removeClass("myclass_2").addClass("yourclass");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery removeClass and addClass method to remove the existing class and then add the renamed class